# Select datatable data based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to select datatable data based on the row's class with the click of a button. For example:

My table:

```
<table id="productsTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each context}}
        <tr>
            <td class="product_id">{{product_id}}</td>
            <td class="brand">{{brand}}</td>
            <td class="category">{{category}}</td>
            <td class="description">{{description}}</td>
            <td class="price">{{price}}</td>
            <th></th>
            <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn-add">Add to Cart</button></th>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I click my `Add to Cart` button, I want it to select `product_id and price` based on its class. Ideally it would be something like:

```
$("button").click(function() {
     id = this.product_id;
     price = this.price;
});
```

Can someone help?

So far the closest I've come up is:

```
var table = $("#productsTable").DataTable();
var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
console.log(data[4]); //selects price
```

But this approach doesn't work for me because the columns might be in different locations from table to table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this.

```
 $("button").click(function() {
            id =  $(this).parent().parent().children('td.product_id').text();
            price = $(this).parent().parent().children('td.price').text();
        });
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/wfefy2xe/)